# How can I add more recent commits into an older Github release?

Tags: git, github, commit, release, git-commit

I’ve created and published a release on Github, but then I commited a change that I would like to have included in the release. On the release page, it says

> 1 commit to master since this release

Is there any way to either republish the release with the new commit included, or change the commit date so that it appears in the release?

Comment: Aren't github releases made off tags? If so, just deleting the tag and making a new one should create a release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to either republish the release with the new commit included,

["Releases"](https://help.github.com/categories/releases/) at Github are just tags. So you can recreate a release just by moving its tag. You can also [edit release](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-and-deleting-releases/) right at Github web interface.

But moving tags is **VERY** inconvenient for everyone who has already forked or cloned you repository so PLEASE don't do that.

Instead create a new bugfix release, that is, create and push a new tag. There is nothing wrong in having feature releases (1.1, 1.2, …) and bugfix releases (1.1.4, 1.1.5, …)

> or change the commit date so that it appears in the release?

No, a release includes commits that are reachable from the tagged commit. Lines of commits, of direct acyclic graph to be precise, not commits by date.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind elaborating on what happens when tags are moved. Does it only affect people who fork/clone the repository since the tag was created? And what if I [delete it](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-delete-a-tag-on-github) and recreate it very soon after?

Comment: *Does it only affect people who fork/clone the repository since the tag was created?* Yes, all of them have to repeat the move.